Summary and plot after MatchIt for specific patient subgroup
I have used Matchit::matchit() to implement 1-to-1 propensity score matching on a dataset and cobalt::love.plot to show covariate balance for the dataset before and after adjustment.
Is it possible to calculate and plot covariate balance for a subset of the dataset? I would like to show the covariate balance for the full dataset, but also for key subsets of the data e.g. for participants in the study who are female.
Here is an example of what I am trying to do, and what I've tried.
library(cobalt)
library(MatchIt)
data("lalonde", package = "cobalt")

m.out1 <- matchit(
  treat ~ age + educ + race + married + nodegree + re74 + re75, 
  data = lalonde,
  method = "nearest", 
  distance = "glm"
) 
love.plot(m.out1) # Covariate Balance for all samples
love.plot(m.out1, data = lalonde[1:10,]) # Covariate balance for subset comprising first 10 samples (doesn't work)


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can use the cluster or subset arguments to love.plot() as stated in the documentation for bal.tab():

cluster
either a vector containing cluster membership for each unit or
a string containing the name of the cluster membership variable in
data or the input object.


subset
a logical or numeric vector denoting whether each observation should
be included or which observations should be included. If logical, it
should have length equal to the number of units. NAs will be treated
as FALSE. This can be used as an alternative to cluster to examine
balance on subsets of the data.

So you should be able to run
love.plot(m.out, cluster = "married")

to get balance within subgroups of married or
love.plot(m.out, subset = lalonde$married == 1)

to just look at balance within the subgroup where married == 1.
In the future, please ask software-related questions on StackOverflow instead of CrossValidated. I check both frequently and am happy to answer questions about any of the packages I maintain.
